# How do I specify where the python dll is located for vim 8?

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to enable python support for Vim 8.0 on Windows 10.

As I understand it I need:

- Vim with python support
- Python installed and on the $path
- matching 32 or 64 bit versions of both

I have tried

- the official 32bit binary, which shows python35.dll with python 3.5.2 and 3
- the 64 bit binary available [from tux project](http://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/complete-x64.7z) which shows python36.dll as the ddynamic_python_dll with python 3.6.1

Each time I've checked the path by typing 'python --version' in cmd and confirming I'm getting the right version.

In all cases I get E370 could not load library.  How do I make sure Vim is looking at the right file?

Answer (score 4):

```
set pythonthreedll="c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python36.dll"
```

And you might *not* want to leave that in your .vimrc while you keep changing everything else around it....